# How can php indexed array be json_encoded as associative array?

Tags: php

Something like:

```
[0 => 'a', 1 => 'b']
```

to json

```
{
    "0": "a",
    "1": "b",
}
```

instead of

```
["a","b"]
```

Comment: Is the array key an incremental value?

Comment: @FreedomPride may or may not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're looking for.
Forcing the JSON Object is the only solution you're looking for.

```
$array = array( '0' => 'a', '1' => 'b', '2' => 'c', '3' => 'c' );
$json = json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
echo $json;
```

Comment: Good answer but not entirely solve my problem. I may have arrays in deeper layers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` option:

```
$array = array(
    0 => 'Banana',
    1 => 'Minions',
    2 => array(
        5 => 'MariaOzawa',
        6 => 'YukiOsawa'
    )
);
$myJsonString = json_encode($MyArray, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
print_r($myJsonString);
```

Then you can see result like this:

```
{"0":"Banana","1":"Minions","2":{"5":"MariaOzawa","6":"YukiOsawa"}}
```

With this way, you can keep your array keys whatever how many layers is it into json_object

Hope this help